# Why am I getting SRID error when doing spatial join in PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, postgis, spatial-query

I have two tables that I wish to join:

- sd_lat_long: This table contains UK locations and their respective latitudes and longitudes
- sd_geo_uk_counties: This table contains UK counties and their respective geometries

I wish to create a view which finds which UK locations intersect with which counties.

Here is a script that I have come up with:

```
--Define list of uk locations and their lat, longs
WITH geo AS ( 
    SELECT 
        uk_locations,
        ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(latitude ,longitude),4326) AS lat_long --set to SRID 4326
    FROM
        sd_lat_long 
),
--Defining the shapefile and transforming the geometry
shp AS (
SELECT 
    county,
    ST_Transform(geometry, 4326) AS geometry --Transformed to SRID 4326 from 27700
FROM 
    sd_geo_uk_counties
WHERE 1=1
)
--Join on intersection of lat_long and the county geometry to assign a county to the UK locations
SELECT
    geo.uk_locations,
    shp.county
FROM 
    geo
LEFT JOIN
     shp
ON
    ST_Intersects(shp.geometry, geo.lat_long)
```

For the shp CTE, I used this post to help: [Why are UK county geometries showing up in the Gulf of Guinea when using PostGIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77648079/why-are-uk-county-geometries-showing-up-in-the-gulf-of-guinea-when-using-postgis/77648921?noredirect=1#comment136923198_77648921)

The problem that I'm facing is that I keep getting an error that appears to be related to the SRID of the geometries that I am using in my script. See error below.
[image]

I firstly had a look at the SRIDs for the geometry fields in the geo and shp CTEs for the script above.

**GEO**:
The lat_long field looked to be fine - i.e. SRID = 4326
Test script:

```
WITH geo AS ( 
    SELECT 
        uk_locations,
        ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(latitude ,longitude),4326) AS lat_long --set to SRID 4326
    FROM
        sd_lat_long 
),  
SELECT
    uk_locations AS geo_field,
    ST_SRID(lat_long) AS srid,
    'geo' AS cte
FROM
    geo
GROUP BY 
1,2, 3
HAVING
srid <> 4326
```

This returned no errors or entries with SRID <> 4326

[image]

**SHP**:
Test script:

```
WITH shp AS (
SELECT 
    ctyua23nm AS county,
    ST_Transform(geometry, 4326) AS geometry
FROM 
    sd_geo_uk_counties
WHERE 1=1
)
SELECT
    county AS geo_field,
    ST_SRID(geometry) AS srid,
    'shp' AS cte
FROM
    shp
GROUP BY 
1,2,3
```

This threw the same original error: [image]

I'm not sure where to go from here, any help would be most appreiated!

Comment: The error might be due to the original SRID of the geometry column in sd_geo_uk_counties. Ensure it's correctly set and compatible with SRID 4326.
Check if the ST_Transform function is correctly transforming the geometries in sd_geo_uk_counties. Verify that both geometries (points and county shapes) are indeed in the same SRID after transformation. Check the data types and ensure there are no null or corrupt geometries.

Answer (score 0):

The `srid` in `sd_geo_uk_counties` is not set, so `0` is assumed and it is an [invalid](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html) value for `st_transform`.

Try setting it first:

```sql
SELECT 
    ctyua23nm AS county,
    ST_Transform(st_srid(geometry,27700), 4326) AS geometry
FROM 
    sd_geo_uk_counties
```

Idealy you would set the srid at the column level and update (once) every geometry to set the srid.

On a side note, you have swapped latitude and longitude when building the point, it should be longitude first: `ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(longitude, latitude),4326) AS lat_long`